# Mobile master page for asp.net site

Tags: asp.net, css, mobile, master-pages

Someone knows where i can find sample master pages for mobile sites in asp.net ?
I thought was just a matter of CSS, but obviously i was wrong..

I'm trying to build the mobile version of a restaurant website...

Comment: Have you tried editing the blank masterpage generated by Visual Studio and replacing the default content with the standard structure needed by e.g. jqTouch or jquery mobile?

Comment: you're not wrong. it is a matter of CSS. see http://html5boilerplate.com/mobile/

Comment: @userGame did this parameters fix the page on mobile ?

Comment: Yes, thank you very much :). Now when i use fennec to see my website running on localhost, i can only spot the upper left-corner of my original design...I think nothing can save me from restyling everithing, right?

Comment: It appears that dynamically loaded images (extracted from a sql database) won't load on the mobile version :(

Comment: @UserGame this is probably a small bug because in my site the images render the same on mobile and on normal. Make a new question about with details...

Comment: @UserGame to make it work correctly you need to redesign it to feet 320 px. To do that you need ether a dynamic width page, or a new page with 320 pixel width max.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I like to confirm, that is not only css. And in the page http://html5boilerplate.com/mobile/ there are some more parameters than just css.

The basic idea is that you page must be able to fit on a size of 320 pixel, or on 200 pixel width.

Second this meta tags are critical to make view correctly the page on mobile

```
<meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="True">
<meta name="MobileOptimized" content="320"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

This tags say to the mobile what is the size that the try to show, if this is not found the mobile is render it as is a 640 or 800 width browser and you get too small text and images.

So in my opinion, set this tags first, then fix your page and see how its look on mobile.

Comment: This post was back in 2011. In 2022, you can omit the "MobileOptimized" line.